# IdHTTP how to send raw body

Tags: http, delphi, indy, idhttp

How i can use `IdHTTP` to send message as `PostMan` dos below:

[image: Headers]
[image: Body]

My first attempt was as follow:

```
function TIdFoo.SendIM(const AID, AMessage: string): Boolean;
const
  _URL = 'https://URL.com/SendMessage';
var
  Params   : TStringStream;
  Response : string;
  LMsg     : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  LMsg := '-----------------------------13932'+
          'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'+
          'Content-Description: message'+ sLineBreak+          '{"message":{"Type":1,"body":"'+AMessage+'"},"to":["'+AID+'"]}'+
          '-----------------------------13932--;'+sLineBreak;
  Params := TStringStream.Create(LMsg, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('authorization', 'Bearer ' + FToken);
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Origin', 'https://www.URL.com');
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36';
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept         := '*/*';
    IdHTTP.Request.Referer        := 'https://www.URL.com/en-us/';
    IdHTTP.Request.Host           := 'URL.com';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, br';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'Accept-Language';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    := 'multipart/mixed; boundary="---------------------------13932"';
    Params.Position               := 0;
    try
      Response := IdHTTP.Post(_URL, Params);
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln('Error on Send Message request: '#13#10, e.Message);
    end;
    Writeln(IdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The second attempt i try it this way

```
function TIdFoo.SendIM(const AID, AMessage: string): Boolean;
const
  _URL = 'https://URL.com/SendMessage';
var
  Params   : TStringStream;
  Response : string;
  LMsg     : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  LMsg := '{"message":{"Type":1,"body":"'+AMessage+'"},"to":["'+AID+'"]}';
  Params := TStringStream.Create(LMsg, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('authorization', 'Bearer ' + FToken);
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Origin', 'https://www.URL.com');
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Description', 'message'); // I addedd this as on PostMan Body
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36';
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept         := '*/*';
    IdHTTP.Request.Referer        := 'https://www.URL.com/en-us/';
    IdHTTP.Request.Host           := 'URL.com';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, br';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'Accept-Language';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    := 'application/json; charset=utf-8'; // I alos changed this as it shown on PostMan body
    Params.Position               := 0;
    try
      Response := IdHTTP.Post(_URL, Params);
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln('Error on Send Message request: '#13#10, e.Message);
    end;
    Writeln(IdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Both attempts gives `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.

Can any advice my what i', doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your first example, your "raw" MIME data is not formatted correctly:

- You are missing a bunch of required line breaks. And don't use the `sLineBreak` constant, as its value is platform-specific.  MIME expects line breaks to use `CRLF` specifically.  Indy has an `EOL` constant for that value.
- You have an erroneous semicolon on the end of the closing boundary line.

You are also not setting the `Request.AcceptEncoding` property correctly.  DO NOT enable encodings manually, unless you are prepared to actually handle them manually in responses (which your code is not).  `TIdHTTP` handles `gzip` and `deflate` encodings for you, if you assign a `TIdZLibCompressorBase`-derived component, like `TIdCompressorZLib`, to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property.  Don't worry about the `br` encoding, it is not widely used.  In short, leave the `Request.AcceptEncoding` at its default and let `TIdHTTP` manage it for you.

You are also not setting the `Request.AcceptLanguage` property correctly.  You should be setting it to `'en-US,en;q=0.8'`, not to `'Accept-Language'`.

Your first example *should* work if you make these fixes, eg:

```
function TIdFoo.SendIM(const AID, AMessage: string): Boolean;
const
  _URL = 'https://URL.com/SendMessage';
var
  Params   : TStringStream;
  Response : string;
  LMsg     : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  LMsg := '-----------------------------13932' + EOL +
          'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' + EOL +
          'Content-Description: message' + EOL +
          EOL +
          '{"message":{"Type":1,"body":"'+AMessage+'"},"to":["'+AID+'"]}' + EOL +
          '-----------------------------13932--' + EOL;
  Params := TStringStream.Create(LMsg, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + FToken);
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Origin', 'https://www.URL.com');
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36';
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept         := '*/*';
    IdHTTP.Request.Referer        := 'https://www.URL.com/en-us/';
    IdHTTP.Request.Host           := 'URL.com';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.8';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    := 'multipart/mixed; boundary="---------------------------13932"';

    try
      Response := IdHTTP.Post(_URL, Params);
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln('Error on Send Message request: '#13#10, e.Message);
    end;
    Writeln(IdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function TIdFoo.SendIM(const AID, AMessage: string): Boolean;
const
  _URL = 'https://URL.com/SendMessage';
var
  Params   : TMemoryStream;
  Response : string;
  LMsg     : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  Params := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    WriteStringToStream(Params, '-----------------------------13932' + EOL);
    WriteStringToStream(Params, 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' + EOL);
    WriteStringToStream(Params, 'Content-Description: message' + EOL);
    WriteStringToStream(Params, EOL);
    WriteStringToStream(Params, '{"message":{"Type":1,"body":"'+AMessage+'"},"to":["'+AID+'"]}' + EOL, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    WriteStringToStream(Params, '-----------------------------13932--' + EOL);
    Params.Position := 0;

    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + FToken);
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Origin', 'https://www.URL.com');
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36';
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept         := '*/*';
    IdHTTP.Request.Referer        := 'https://www.URL.com/en-us/';
    IdHTTP.Request.Host           := 'URL.com';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.8';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    := 'multipart/mixed; boundary="---------------------------13932"';

    try
      Response := IdHTTP.Post(_URL, Params);
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln('Error on Send Message request: '#13#10, e.Message);
    end;
    Writeln(IdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function TIdFoo.SendIM(const AID, AMessage: string): Boolean;
const
  _URL = 'https://URL.com/SendMessage';
var
  Params   : TMemoryStream;
  Response : string;
  LMsg     : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  Params := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    with TStreamWriter.Create(Params, TEncoding.UTF8) do
    try
      NewLine := EOL;
      WriteLine('-----------------------------13932');
      WriteLine('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
      WriteLine('Content-Description: message');
      WriteLine;
      WriteLine('{"message":{"Type":1,"body":"'+AMessage+'"},"to":["'+AID+'"]}');
      WriteLine('-----------------------------13932--');
    finally
      Free;
    end;
    Params.Position := 0;

    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + FToken);
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Origin', 'https://www.URL.com');
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36';
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept         := '*/*';
    IdHTTP.Request.Referer        := 'https://www.URL.com/en-us/';
    IdHTTP.Request.Host           := 'URL.com';
    IdHTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.8';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType    := 'multipart/mixed; boundary="---------------------------13932"';

    try
      Response := IdHTTP.Post(_URL, Params);
      Result := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln('Error on Send Message request: '#13#10, e.Message);
    end;
    Writeln(IdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

In your second example, your "raw" data is just the JSON by itself, not any MIME wrapping it.  You are putting MIME headers in the HTTP headers, where they don't belong.  This example will not work if the server expects MIME data and not just raw JSON data.

You are also making the same mistakes with the `Request.AcceptEncoding` and `Request.AcceptLanguage` properties.

---

Since you are posting data in MIME format, an easier way to handle this *would have been* to use Indy's `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` class instead, and let it handle the MIME formatting for you.  However, that class does not currently support:

- setting the stream's `RequestContentType` property to a custom value (in this case, `'multipart/mixed'` instead of `'multipart/form-data'`).  Though, you can use an accessor class to accomplish this, since the `FRequestContentType` member is `protected`.
- omitting the `Content-Disposition: form-data` header on individual fields.  This might trip up servers that are not expecting `form-data` submissions.
- specifying the `Content-Description` MIME header at all (see [Add support for user-defined MIME headers in TIdMultipartFormDataStream](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/172) in Indy's issue tracker on GitHub).

So you will have to continue resorting to formatting the MIME data manually.  You just have to make sure you get it right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the magnificent answer