# IdHTTP how to send x-www-form-urlencoded body

Tags: delphi, http-post, ebay-api, idhttp, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have tested POST function in PostMan to do POST function with body parameters as below:

[image]

[image]

Here is eBay's document for this function:

```
  HTTP method:   POST
  URL (Sandbox): https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token

  HTTP headers:
    Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization = Basic <B64-encoded-oauth-credentials>

  Request body:
    grant_type=authorization_code
    code=<authorization-code-value>
    redirect_uri=<RuName-value>
```

My first attempt was as follow:

```
function udxEBayExchangeAuthCodeForUserToken(AAuthCode: String; AIsProduction: Boolean): String;
var
  xRequestBody: TStringStream;
begin
  with objHTTP.Request do begin
    CustomHeaders.Clear;
    ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Basic ' + 'V2VpbmluZ0MtV2VpbmluZ0M';
  end;

  xRequestBody := TStringStream.Create('grant_type=' + 'authorization_code' + ','
                                     + 'code=' + 'v%5E1.1%23i%5E1%23f%5E0%23r%5E1%23I%5E3%23p%5E3' + ','
                                     + 'redirect_uri=' + 'myredirecturlnameinsandbox',
                                        TEncoding.UTF8);

  try
    try
      Result := objHTTP.Post('https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token', xRequestBody);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error on request: ' + #13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    xRequestBody.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Second attempt tried with below code for Body

```
  xRequestBody := TStringStream.Create('grant_type=' + 'authorization_code' + '&'
                                     + 'code=' + AAuthCode + '&'
                                     + 'redirect_uri=' + gsRuName,
                                        TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Both attempts give HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

I have done some searching in Stack Overflow, and this is the closest question. The only different part is body of POST.

[IdHTTP how to send raw body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665349/idhttp-how-to-send-raw-body)

Can anyone please advise me what is correct way to assign POST body part?
Thanks.

Comment: There are several thing in the code that you do wrong. Besides that, you say that you're getting `400 Bad Request`, but that's the same as in Postman. So what is the real question here? How to POST via Postman? How to POST via Indy? How to use eBay API? Anyhow, I pasted your sample code into a plain VCL application in Delphi 10.2 and I got `401 Unathorized`. Is there something you didn't show us?

Comment: @PeterWolf Thank you for your help. Three parameters (['Authorization'], 'code=', 'redirect_uri=') were not pasted completely in sample code. This POST call is following with another GET call to get the value of code inside POST body, which expires in 299 seconds after it is granted from eBay. With your comments, now I found that Postman has status "400 Bad Request". Let me do some more tests in Postman.

Comment: One question: *{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"
}* This message is shown in Postman and I thought it is feedback from server. If so, does this mean that POST call is ok but with invalid authorization code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your POST request made it to the server and it responded with the JSON content. The server gives hint why the request can't be succesfully served (401 - authorization issue, 400 - malformed request). In my first comment I wrote you have some issues in your code. See Remy's answer, which pretty much sums them up.

Comment: @PeterWolf Thank you for your quick reply. I am doing more tests with Remy's codes.

Comment: When server gave both 401 - authorization issue and 400 - malformed request error, they stand for different mistakes inside POST call. I don't know which one is the real reason for unsuccessful calling. Is there fucntion inside idHTTP to get same feedback information from server like POSTMAN? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *preferred* way to send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with `TIdHTTP` is to use the overloaded `TIdHTTP.Post()` method that takes a `TStrings` as input.  You are not sending your `TStringStream` data in the proper `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

You don't need to use the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property to setup `Basic` authorization.  `TIdHTTP` has built-in support for `Basic`, simply use the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserName` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties as needed, and set the `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` property to true.

Try this instead:

```pascal
function udxEBayExchangeAuthCodeForUserToken(AAuthCode: String; AIsProduction: Boolean): String;
var
  xRequestBody: TStringList;
begin
  with objHTTP.Request do
  begin
    Clear;
    ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    BasicAuthentication := True;
    UserName := ...;
    Password := ...;
  end;

  xRequestBody := TStringList.Create;
  try
    xRequestBody.Add('grant_type=' + 'authorization_code');
    xRequestBody.Add('code=' + AAuthCode);
    xRequestBody.Add('redirect_uri=' + 'myredirecturlnameinsandbox');

    try
      Result := objHTTP.Post('https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token', xRequestBody);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error on request: ' + #13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    xRequestBody.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to send your own `TStringStream`, try this instead:

```pascal
function udxEBayExchangeAuthCodeForUserToken(AAuthCode: String; AIsProduction: Boolean): String;
var
  xRequestBody: TStringStream;
begin
  with objHTTP.Request do
  begin
    Clear;
    ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    BasicAuthentication := True;
    UserName := ...;
    Password := ...;
  end;

  xRequestBody := TStringStream.Create('grant_type=' + 'authorization_code' + '&'
                                     + 'code=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(AAuthCode){'v%5E1.1%23i%5E1%23f%5E0%23r%5E1%23I%5E3%23p%5E3'} + '&'
                                     + 'redirect_uri=' + 'myredirecturlnameinsandbox',
                                        TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    try
      xRequestBody.Position := 0;

      Result := objHTTP.Post('https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token', xRequestBody);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error on request: ' + #13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    xRequestBody.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation and sample code. I did try both and same error is still happened. One thing I didn't change is objHTTP.Request.UserName/Password. There is only Authorization used for eBay API call and I think username is already encoded inside Authorization code.

Comment: I did more tests in Postman with fresh AuthCode, with valid/invalid ['Authorization'], server will give different error: invalid_grant (400 Bad Request)/invalid_client (401 Unauthorized). Tried same inside my application, error codes are same as Postman: 400 vs 401. It looks POST call is pasted to server properly but there is something else not right. It might be 'code=' inside POST call's body or others. Keep testing with Remy's new code and looking for further advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was troubled by this problem, but the answer didn't work very much. Later, I used packet capturing to see the actual content sent. For friends with the same problems.

```
function TFormMain.init_web_account(): Boolean;
var
  strTmp: Ansistring;
  PostStringData: TstringStream;
  idhttp1: Tidhttp;
  json, json_array1: TQjson;
  itype_version: integer;
  ifunction_version: integer;
  s: string;
  url: ansistring;
  idMultiPartFormDataStream:TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  try
    result := False;
    idhttp1 := TIdHTTP.Create();
    PostStringData := TStringStream.Create;



    //init_string  http://x.x.x.x:8000/user/key?ke1=v1&k2=v2
    strTmp := //
      'strdogsoftid=' + edtDogNumber.Text + //
      '&chipid=' + '' + //
      '&status=' + '0' +  //
      '&reg_user_name=' + edtRegName.Text + //
      '&reg_init_date=' + formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', dtpRegCodeGenDate.Date) + //
      '&lease_expiration=' + formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', dtp_lease_expiration.Date) + //
      '&renew_last_date=' + '' + //
      '&mobile=' + '' + //
      '&weixin=' + '' + //
      '&memo=' + '' + //
      '&function_version=' + IntToStr(rgVersion.ItemIndex) + //
      '&type_version=' + IntToStr(itype_version); //

    url := 'http://x.x.x.x:8000/user/' + edtDogNumber.Text;
    PostStringData.Clear;
    PostStringData.WriteString(strTmp);


    try

      idhttp1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';



      s := idhttp1.Post(url, PostStringData); 
      result := True;


    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        showmessage(s);
        result := False; 
        exit;
      end;

    end;
  finally
    PostStringData.Free;
    idhttp1.Free;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your new code, dreamnyj. I would like to know how to do packet capturing to see actual content idHTTP sent.

Comment: First, we use postman to construct a standard request, and then we use packet capturing software to capture the actual content sent. The capture software sets our target address to achieve filtering. For specific package capturing software, please search by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TNetHTTPClient you can use the "System.Net.Mime" unit to manage the multipart form data by HTTP Post and manage request too.

I use Delphi 10.4.2